# Как правильно импортировать столбец?

Tags: база-данных, excel

Есть 2 базы (.csv). В одной ID бренда и его название, в другой просто ID

Задача в том, чтобы заменить во второй базе ID на название, соответствующее этому ID из первой.

Подскажите плиз, средствами exel или notepad++ это можно как-то сделать?

[image: exel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открыть *.csv* в двух книгах *Excel*.

Во второй таблице в свободном столбце в строке 1 записать формулу (диапазон не обязательно писать вручную, достаточно выделить два столбца в первой книге):

```
=ВПР(C1;донор.csv!$A:$B;2;)
```

Если работа не разовая, лучше указать ссылку на конкретный диапазон с данными (строки с 1 по...)

Протянуть формулу по строкам.

Выделить диапазон с формулами, копировать, выделить диапазон столбца *С*, *Спецвставка  - Вставить как значения*. Вспомогательный столбец с формулами удалить.

Если *id* не найден, вместо *name* будет значение ошибки `#Н/Д`. Диапазон выделен, `Ctrl+H`, `НАЙТИ` - #Н/Д, `ЗАМЕНИТЬ` - ничего не пишем, `Заменить все`

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У меня Excel с английским интерфейсом, так что придется Вам искать соответствия терминам и названиям меню.

1. Объединяете CSV файлы в один Excel файл с двумя вкладками, пусть их названия будут **brand_names**, **brand_products**
2. Выделяете все данные в столбцах **A**,**B** в **brand_names**. В меню `Formulas` выбираете `Define Name`. Называете диапазон `BrandNames`. Область действия - по умолчанию - вся книга.
3. Во вкладке **brand_products** после столбца **C** вставляете новый столбец.
4. В ячейке **D2** определяете формулу `=VLOOKUP(C2,BrandNames,2)`
5. Размножаете формулу вниз на остальные строки.
6. Теперь в столбце **D** у Вас названия имен брендов
7. (Опционально) Выделяете все значения в столбце **D**. Копируете в буфер обмена `Ctrl-C`.
   Кликаете правой кнопкой мыши по выделению. Выбираете `вставить значения` (`values`). Удаляете столбец **C**

Comment: Если *id* в таблице-доноре несортированы, в `ВПР (VLOOKUP)` нужно указывать точный поиск (интервальный просмотр - 0 или ЛОЖЬ)